# JPA query using a database function to use a specific index

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.3

I have a table named vehicle which has a column named VIN.
Users need the ability to search based on the last 6 characters of the VIN.
So I've added an index in Postgres like so:

```
  CREATE INDEX "ix_vin_last_6" ON vehicle(RIGHT(vin,6));
```

I added a few test records as follows:

```
LAST6VIN_A_123456
LAST6VIN_B_123456
LAST6VIN_C_123456
```

Using SpringDataJPA repository, here is one way to query for the above test records:

```
List<Vehicle> findByVinEndingWith(String vin)
```

But the JPA query generated above uses a LIKE clause, like so:

```
where
    vehicle0_.vin like ?
```

How do I make a repository method to query for the above 3 test records using the last 6 characters that uses the index I created above so that it generates this query:

```
SELECT vin, year, make, model
FROM vehicle 
WHERE RIGHT(vin,6) = '123456';
```

The above query works fine when I execute it using pgadmin command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPQL supports (since JPA 2.1 IIRC) calling arbitrary database functions using `function`:

```
select v from Vehicle v
where function('RIGHT', v.vin, 6) = :endOfVin
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked for me. I was able to use EXPLAIN to confirm that it is using the relevant index with this query. Thanks