# JPA - How to select from a database function?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following SQL query in T-SQL:

```
SELECT a.ReportDate,
    a.Value,
    a.Quantity,
    a.ID,
    a.Code
FROM AQF.fCalc(@data) a
```

`@data` is a `varbinary`. I'm trying to replicate this query using JPA. (I'm actually using Spring Data JPA 1.10.2.) I have the following defined in `MyRepository`:

```
@Query("SELECT a "
        + "FROM function('AQF.fCalc', :data) a "
       )
List<MyClass> getCalcData(@Param("data") byte[] data);
```

`MyClass` is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data // using lombok to create setters, getters, etc.
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Date reportDate;
    private BigDecimal value;
    private BigDecimal quantity;
    private String code;

}
```

When I call getCalcData, I receive the following error:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: function
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1501) [hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]...
```

How can I call the function AQF.fCalc (and pass in the byte array) using JPA?

**Update 1**

I've now tried using a native query too, but now I get an error stating:

```
java.sql.SQLException: An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued Function : 
System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: Data, Report. Line 24, position 804.
```

Here's the test code for the native query in `MyRepository`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a.code "
        + "FROM AQF.fCalc(?1) a",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getCalcData(byte[] data);
```

**Update 2**

I was able to resolve the error noted in "Update 1" above. The byte array of data in the `getCalcData` was corrupted. Once I resolved that issue, the error no longer appeared. So, now I can run as a native query. However, I would still like to know how to use JPQL to make this function call.

Comment: That is not valid JPQL so try specifying it as a native query http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries

Comment: OK. Thanks for the comment. I referenced this post:  I'm probably misunderstanding something, but it seems JPQL supports (since JPA 2.1) this syntax according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115100/jpa-query-using-a-database-function-to-use-a-specific-index). At any rate I changed to use a native query and now I don't get the error but I also do not get any results returned.

Comment: Sorry but I found the issue of no results. Now, I get the error as noted in the above updated post.

Comment: That is an exception on the DB side so looks like your function is at least now being called. Thanks for the clarification on JPQL and function calls. Hibernate 4.3+ implements  JPA 2.1 so I would have expected your original (non-native) call to work if your Hibernate version =>4.3

Comment: Yes. It now appears that I can at least make the call to the DB function using the code in the Update section. I'm not sure why the original code didn't work though. I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.10.2 which I think is pulling in Hibernate version => 4.3. Not sure how to confirm that?  I see the jar `hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar` on my classpath. Also, I switched from jTds 1.3.1 jar to Microsoft's sqljdbc 4.2. Now I getting a different error message ` com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 4 is out of range. The index 4 is out of range.` followed by

Comment: `Error preparing CallableStatement`

Answer (score -2):

You can use **StoredProcedureQuery**. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html)

> Interface used to control stored procedure query execution.

Refer this **sample** code.

**Assume** your SQL function name is sales_tax in this example.

```
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        // Create call stored procedure
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sales_tax");
        // set parameters
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("subtotal", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tax", Double.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("subtotal", 1f);
        // execute SP
        storedProcedure.execute();
        // get result
        Double tax = (Double)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");
        System.out.println("Tax is: " + tax);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

Comment: I need use the function in a select statement. The function returns a table. I don't see how a stored procedure call will work.

Comment: function is another name for storeprocedure

Comment: How would I use to solve my question in the OP? The function returns a table. I'm not clear how you would define the type of the out parameter.

Comment: @James, did you find a solution. I have the same issue :(

Comment: @Hicham, Yes, I was able to  select from a database function. I had to use a native query.

Comment: Thank you @James

Comment: @James, you know, you can answer your own question and mark your solution as the accepted one if it solved your issue.